# Does a shared ViewModel between fragments survive if activity gets destroyed?

Tags: android, viewmodel

I'm planning on sharing a ViewModel between an Activity and two Fragments as such:

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<Item> selected = new MutableLiveData<Item>();

    public void select(Item item) {
        selected.setValue(item);
    }

    public LiveData<Item> getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
}


public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel model;

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener(item -> {
            model.select(item);
        });
    }
}

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        SharedViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        model.getSelected().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), item -> {
           // Update the UI.
        });
    }
}
```

If I remember correctly, if the OS gets low on memory, a paused Activity could potentially be destroyed while the current visible fragment survives. If this occurs, and the fragment is sharing a ViewModel with the destroyed activity, will the ViewModel survive with the fragment?

Comment: if you have one activity and multiple fragments in it and share the same viewmodel then the view model survived that's what the main purpose of viewmodel

Comment: `a paused Activity could potentially be destroyed while the current visible fragment survives.`  how do you imagine this will work, are you able to show fragments without having them contained within an activity ?

Comment: setRetainInstance(true) sets fragment retained. Retained fragment is not destroyed across activity lifecycle. Unfortunately  setRetainInstance is deprecated.

Comment: @a_local_nobody yes, if I remember correctly, if the OS is low on memory and Activity is not visible, then it becomes a candidate to be destroyed to free up memory. I think there's even an interview question that ask whether a fragment can survive without an activity.

Comment: @BurhanKhanzada I just wasn't sure if a shared ViewModel keeps track of multiple lifecycles. So if Activity gets destroyed for memory purposes, does the shared ViewModel's onCleared method get called, even if the current fragment is visible?

Comment: @james fields To free up memory, Android kills the entire virtual machine with all activities and fragments in it. This is one process.

Comment: Fragments can only be retained when the activity is destroyed in configuration changes (rotations and so on). Only if use deprecated setRetainInstance(true) method (function).

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate As mentioned in Saving UI States, ViewModel objects can handle configuration changes, so you don't need to worry about state in rotations or other cases. However, if you need to handle system-initiated process death, you might want to use onSaveInstanceState() as backup.